# Updating Magento Country Directory

Tags: php, magento, usps

This issue specifically involves the country Netherlands Antilles, which was apparently disolved in 2010. The issue is that its still listed in my Magento store and when customers select it they get no shipping options because the USPS API spits it out saying that this is not a valid country name. This worked a few months ago so I'm guessing that the USPS recently updated something. I’m looking for a way to update this data to reflect the updates but none of the actual country names are in the database. Am I going to have to update Zend files for this as well?

Comment: Not sure what you can do. The Netherlands Antilles was split into several independent island groups. So there is not a one-to-one replacement. See this reuters news article: http://www.reuters.com/article/2010/10/10/us-caribbean-islands-idUSTRE69913J20101010

Comment: Yeah I had thought of just sending the province instead as an override but because its not a one to one, I would only solve the issue for two of the islands.

Comment: You also should add their domain names to Zend/Validate/Hostname.php

Answer (score 0):

You will need to update the `directory_*` tables with the new regions, and you will also need to update the entries in *`Zend/Locale.php`* and *`Zend/Locale/Data.php`*.